# How to set RTC alarm from script or terminal in OSX?

Tags: macos, shell, boot, alarm

I have a iMac mini running OSX for powerpc which I want to use for remote backup.

The backup will be run via a bash script with rsync over ssh. To save energy the computer is automatically put to sleep and wakes up by RTC alarm clock (which can be set in powersetting via system settings).

Now I would like to be able to set the startup time of the backup-pc from my backup script instead of having to do this from a graphical shell.  In a linux kernel this can be done by writing the wakuptime to

> /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm

or by using nvram-wakeup.

I have been looking for a solution which can do this in OSX but was up to now not able to find one. Nvram setting can be read and written by use of the command nvram but in the listing of all variables no alarm time settings are available. Also I found an app 
Alarm Clock Pro which claims it can do this, but this is a big paid application which to me does not make sense for only writing some bytes to rtc-alarm clock.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent seems to be:

```
pmset schedule wake "mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss"
```

Have a look at:

```
man pmset
```

to be sure to use the correct options which will fit.

Comment: Thanks! Had to change it a bit because it would not run like suggested, but pmset is the way to go. Ended up with this:
sudo pmset repeat wakeorpoweron MTWRFSU HH:MM:SS
In which MTWRFSU are the days of the week.